Posting list of object on form submit in Thymeleaf and spring MVC
I have a class called PatientDto at the back-end side.
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PatientDto {
    private String nationalId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Phone> phones;
}

Also a class called Phone:
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Phone {
    private String phoneNumber;
}

Assume that I have two input elements in my html Thymeleaf for getting two phone numbers from user:
<form th:method="post" th:action="@{/reception/savePatient}" th:object="${patientDto}" >
 <input type="text" th:field="*{nationalId}" id="nationalId">
 <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" id="firstName">
 <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" id="lastName">
 <input type="text" id="phoneNumber1">
 <input type="text" id="phoneNumber2">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="savePatientBtn">Save</button>
</form>

Controller:
 @GetMapping
    public String getReceptionView(Model model){
        PatientDto patientDto = new PatientDto();
        model.addAttribute("patientDto", patientDto);
        return "reception";
    }

    @PostMapping("/reception/savePatient")
    public String savePatient(@ModelAttribute("patientDto") PatientDto patientDto){
        System.out.println("???????????? reception>>> " + patientDto.toString());
        return "reception";
    }

How can I post these two phone numbers as a list of phones as part of the PatientDto object on form submit?
What will be the values for "th:field" of these two phone numbers?
I appreciate your helps

It should look like this:
<input type="text" th:field="*{phones[0].phoneNumber}">
<input type="text" th:field="*{phones[1].phoneNumber}">

(Where phoneNumber is the correct field name on the Phone object.)
If your phones list has elements in it already, you can use a loop instead, but you must use preprocessing for the th:field attribute.  Like this:
<input th:each="phone, i: *{phones}" type="text" th:field="*{phones[__${i.index}__].phoneNumber}" />

